# Calling C# from JAVA for mobile devices

Tags: c#, java, .net, reflection

Is it possible to call C# code from java code running on a mobile device using some sort of reflection methods?

Comment: What do you mean by "in mobile device"? Your question is *very* unclear at the moment.

Comment: I've meant mobile phone which has support for running java apps

Comment: Are you asking if you can run C# code on a mobile device that has support for java? Or are you asking if you can call C# code from java code running on a mobile device maybe?

Comment: I've meant calling C# code from JAVA Application

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the device you might want to look at [MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch) or [MonoDroid](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid). They allow you to directly run C# code from the mobile device.

---

In terms of calling C# code from java, I'm not sure if the above will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you can wrap the C# interface into a C function/C++ class, then you can possibly call the C/C++ class from Java using JNI.

Answer (score 0):

Java gets compiled into bytecode using Java's JVM or Dalvik on android. C# will have an equivelant distinct compiler. You cannot pass methods between the two uless you use some standard communication that allows interoperability like XML, Corba  ...